# Search string using RegEx for repeated letters and outputting into two-dimensional array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I just started getting into RegEx. So far I have something like this but it looks like my pattern is off.

```
function hasRepeatedLetters(str) {
  var patt = /[a-zA-Z]/g;
  var result = patt.exec(str);
  return result;
}
console.log(hasRepeatedLetters('aaBcDDbcca'));
```

I'd like to be able to input any argument with a combo of letters and the output to be a two-dimensional array with the first value being the repeated letter and the second value being the repeated letters length.

[["a",3],["b",1],["B",1],["c",3],["D",2]]

Comment: How would you count repetitions for when the same letter occurs twice but separated by another letter (like `'aba'`)? Is the desired result `[["a", 2], ["b", 1]]` or `[["a", 1], ["b", 1], ["a", 1]]`?

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution, using `Array#forEach` function.

```js
var str = 'aaBcDDbcca'.split(''), obj = {};
    str.forEach(v => obj[v] ? obj[v]++ : obj[v] = 1);
var res = Object.keys(obj).map(v => [v, obj[v]]);
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
```

Personally, I would suggest you to keep it as an object.

```js
var str = 'aaBcDDbcca'.split(''), obj = {};
    str.forEach(v => obj[v] ? obj[v]++ : obj[v] = 1);
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a map / object based solution

```
var str = 'aaBcDDbcca';
var map = {}; // create a hash for keys and their counts
// loop over all characters and then add count
Array.from(str).forEach(function(character) {
  map[character] = map[character] ? map[character] + 1 : 1;
});
// finally, convert map to a 2D array with 1st item as key and second item as count
var counts = Object.keys(map).map(function(key) {
  return [key, map[key]];
})
console.log(counts);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an ES6 `Map` for this, which has some nice features:

- a map's `set` method returns the map again
- the spread syntax applied on a map produces the desired array of pairs

```js
function hasRepeatedLetters(str) {
  return [...[...str].reduce( (acc, c) => acc.set(c, (acc.get(c) || 0) + 1), new Map )];
}
console.log(hasRepeatedLetters('aaBcDDbcca'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```